# How to do a radial fade on a canvas image?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have an image . When a user clicks it with mouse I want to get the pixels where of mouse position and fade the image at a particular radius where the mouse is clicked?

check this fiddle : `"http://jsfiddle.net/qFuDr/711/"`

When I click the mouse and then move even I release the mouse
Pixels get cleared and background is visible

I want to clear the pixels smoothly and in circle and also want to calculate percentage of pixels removed

Hope you understand my question

Comment: i created an example for you using `createRadialGradient` there is no need to use masks in this scenario. Me, and @icktoofay were overcomplicating the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of `globalCompositeOperation` and `createRadialGradient` i made a simple demo here (http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/T7qGh/4)

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    var rect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = event.pageX - rect.left,
        y = event.pageY - rect.top;

    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.save();
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';

    var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0, x, y, 500);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,1)');
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
    context.fillStyle = gradient;

    // repeat to intensify the fade
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.restore();
});
```

Comment: +1 because radial gradient+compositing will accomplish the task. BTW, I think the questioner wants the opposite of the effect you illustrate--they want the image fully visible at the mouse position and fading out over the radius of the effect.

Comment: Oh so like this http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/T7qGh/5/ :)

Comment: I want to clear the image at mouse position in a small radius and display background

Comment: you should be able to, heres an example of animating http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/T7qGh/8/

Comment: I want to do it like this , but in this example its rectangle and is not smooth , I want in circle http://jsfiddle.net/qFuDr/711.

Its a type of scratch

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `<canvas>` tag. In particular, you can create a canvas. Then you create a clipping mask that excludes only the area you wish to exclude. Then draw the old image into it. Your new canvas will contain the result. You can then clear out the old canvas and draw in the image from the new canvas, which you can then discard. When creating the clipping mask, be careful about winding.

The advantage of this method over modifying image data directly, besides conceptual simplicity, is that it works with cross-origin image sources. Cross-origin images cannot have their image data inspected or manipulated, but can be drawn and clipped as desired.

Comment: you could also use `createRadialGradient` and `globalCompositeOperation` to get a smoother effect.